# What is the correct way to “clear" a std::string_view?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdstring, string-view

I see this post: [c++ - Why doesn't std::string_view have assign() and clear() methods? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346060/why-doesnt-stdstring-view-have-assign-and-clear-methods), so `string_view` does not contain `clear` function.

But in my case, I have a `string_view` as a class member variable, and sometimes, I would like to reset it to an empty string. Currently, I'm using this way:

```
sv = "";
```

Which looks OK, but I'd see other suggestions, thanks!

Comment: A string view isn't a container in itself, it's just a *view* of another string. As such, the assignment you show doesn't attempt to modify the other string, it merely makes the view reference another string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is to set the size of the string_view to zero, then what you're doing is OK (at the cost of a byte somewhere in your binary).

There are alternatives in the post that you referenced:

- `sv = {}`
- `sv = sv.substr(0, 0)`

Yet another way:

- `sv.remove_prefix(sv.size())`

Comment: I think the `sv = {}` is the best and simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An empty "" string is still a string of length zero. While that will work, `data()` will not return a `nullptr` the way it would for a truly empty `string_view`. If you do want to reset the `string_view`, it would be best to assign an empty `string_view` to it: `sv = string_view{};`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so the empty `string_view` which constructed from `{}` should be the best solution.

Comment: I'm not really happy with your idea of a "truly empty `string_view`". All `string_view`s of length zero compare equal.